# SENSOR_DELAY_GAME: how much is it?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm working on a game and I need to synchronize two player object controlling mechanisms: one is an on-screen touch controller and second is the G-Sensor. On-screen controller must be initialized with a value in seconds, so I need to know how much seconds does `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME` mean. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the Constant value or how long between each poll when its set to SENSOR_DELAY_GAME ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a definite answer into your question, in a meaning that this is device depended. Except from that, keep in mind that even if you define a certain delay for your sensor, the Sensor Manager may return results faster or slower than what you specified. For your case, i think the best approach is to take the average time (in seconds) between two consecutive polls after a certain amount of time that your sensor is running, initialized with the `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME` flag, and pass that time to your on-screen controller initialization.

Answer (score 33):

Taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

> The default data delay is suitable for monitoring typical screen
>   orientation changes and uses a delay of 200,000 microseconds. You can
>   specify other data delays, such as **SENSOR_DELAY_GAME (20,000
>   microsecond delay)**, **SENSOR_DELAY_UI (60,000 microsecond delay)**, or
>   **SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST (0 microsecond delay)**. As of Android 3.0 (API
>   Level 11) you can also specify the delay as an absolute value (in
>   microseconds).
>
> The delay that you specify is only a **suggested delay**. The Android
>   system and other applications can alter this delay. As a best
>   practice, you should specify the largest delay that you can because
>   the system typically uses a smaller delay than the one you specify
>   (that is, **you should choose the slowest sampling rate that still meets
>   the needs of your application**). Using a larger delay imposes a lower
>   load on the processor and therefore uses less power.